# Transition component Vuejs - Not working - Differences between inner and outer

Tags: javascript, css, transition, vuejs2

### EDIT Simplify the question

http://jsfiddle.net/bf830qoq/

Why the transition in that minimalist example does not work? (It mimics the real case in my code)

### Former post

I would like to apply a transition on a custom component in VueJs 2, depending on v-if condition.

I tried to put the **transition inner** the component loading :

### Parent component

```
     <loading v-if="shared.loading"></loading>
```

### Loading.vue

```
<template>
  <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div class="loading-container">
           <div class="container-no-text">
               <div class="title-no">Loading</div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </transition>
</template>


<script>
    import Store from '../store.js'
    export default{
        data () {
            return {
                shared: Store.state,
            }
        },
    }
</script>


<style>

    .slide-fade-enter-active {
        transition: all .3s ease;
    }
    .slide-fade-leave-active {
        transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
    }
    .slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
        /* .slide-fade-leave-active for <2.1.8 */ {
        transform: translateX(10px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

It simply does not work, the login disappears without any animation.

I tried to mimic the situation with JSFiddle :

- Outer transition : http://jsfiddle.net/0v0wyLv0/ WORKING
- Inner transition : http://jsfiddle.net/jpcays2b/ NOT WORKING

### Here are the questions:

1. Why the second JSFiddle does not work (the inner one)?
2. Why on my code the "outer" does not work?
3. How can I make the loading component disappear smoothly?

### Example which is working

https://jsfiddle.net/er3tjyh0/

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As par the implementation of transition in [vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components), transition wrapper component allows you to add entering/leaving transitions for any element or component in the following contexts:

- Conditional rendering (using v-if)
- Conditional display (using v-show)
- Dynamic components
- Component root nodes

From the docs:

When an element wrapped in a transition component is inserted or removed, this is what happens:

- Vue will automatically sniff whether the target element has CSS transitions or animations applied. If it does, CSS transition classes will be added/removed at appropriate timings.
- If the transition component provided JavaScript hooks, these hooks will be called at appropriate timings.
- If no CSS transitions/animations are detected and no JavaScript hooks are provided, the DOM operations for insertion and/or removal will be executed immediately on next frame (Note: this is a browser animation frame, different from Vue’s concept of nextTick).

That's why transition will only work, when it is wrapping the `v-if` and not when it is inside, thats how it is implemented.

Comment: Then could you explain why such a thing is working: https://jsfiddle.net/er3tjyh0/. The v-if is at the component level and the transition is inside the component. That is exactly what I'm trying to redo

Comment: @Leo I have replied on the question, you missed name attribute with transition, see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bf830qoq/1/